# Identify this song?

Tags: music

Is anyone able to let me know what the first song in this medley is (sung by Yaakov Shwekey & Yitzy Waldner)? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMI1lr10HGs

I'm looking to find it so I can track down the actual album version to buy.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: comparative religion?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin How would it be comparative religion?

Comment: @Scimonster that's my question. Someone voted to close as comparative religion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "ובכן אבא אליך ה׳ מלך מלכי המלכים ואפיל תחנתי ועיני לך תלויות עד שתחנני ותשמע תפלתי להזמין לי בנים ובנות" ("so I come before you, God, king of kings' kings, and drop my supplication, and my eyes are hung on you until you grace me and hear my prayer to prepare me sons and daughters") from a prayer widely attributed to the author of שני לחות הברית and recited by some, especially (I think) on ערב ראש חדש סיון.

Perhaps someone else can speak to the melody's provanence.